# it is possible to rig a character with multiples objects?

Tags: modeling, animation

I just want to know if I make a rigging for a 3D character who has at least 6 differents objects (lower body, boots, upper body, head, eyes, hair&eyeslashes...see the picture.
[image]

I do not want to joint all the mesh parts , because I am afraid to lose their own UVs map , (I see some post to not loose uv of every single objects) but I am not user well how to do, by the way, I am asking a punctual asking, can I rig differents pieces of the mesh ? (boots, pants , head, jacket, hand,eyes) what about the vertex weith ? (I am going to use riggify addon).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can:
Actually the armature is a modifier that creates relationship between a bone and a vertex group with the same exact name. If a mesh receives form an armature a request to move a non existing vertex group, it simply ignores the instruction.
So you will have to add an armature modifier to every mesh and create as many vertex groups as bones related with that part of the mesh.
You will have to manually assign weights.

For the main part of the armature you can select the relative mesh, select the armature press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and choose "with empty groups"; this procedure will automatically create a vertex group for every bone of the armature marked as "deform", ready to be weighted (you can then delete the unnecessary vertex groups).

Comment: I see some cg artist model a 3d character ,every single part, and then rig, for example a jacket is near to the head, but never join,  so this objects can animate? so the bone search the information of the vertex group assigned to the group (head vertex group, jacket vertex group, pants vertex group) ?

Comment: I'm not sure to fully understand your question (sorry, i'm from Italy), but a bone named "head" will have effect on a vertex group named "head" of a mesh which has an armature modifier pointed to the armature which contains the "head" bone (you can even have multiple armatures cross-controlling multiple objects, but it's not common).

Comment: Ok , not proble, I just want only know about to animate or rigging with differents objects , ok it is possible, thanks.