# rigging a character with armor that is in loose parts

Tags: modeling, rigging

So I have an idea for an animation that was supposed to be published by now, ut I keep having problems with my character rigs.

Let me explain I have a model that works extremely well with the rig I created but the armor I modeled to be on the mesh will not be rigged I have looked it up everywhere I can think of and every variation of this question but I still need help.

I tried using this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVfTRwXpmuQ It was helpful for the most part but I couldn't get the armor to not bend and deform the mesh.

Here is a picture of the character and the armor. One of the problems might be that because of the way I created it it is made in tons of little objects.

I cannot just recreate this character either like I said I am supposed to have published this animation by now.

Comment: Your picture is missing. Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71730/it-is-possible-to-rig-a-character-with-multiples-objects